# Work with threads

Tags: java, android, multithreading, callable

I have the following task:

1. Download image from web
2. Create another image using it
3. Save image to SD card and show it

I need to do every step into another thread.
It seems, that when I'm done with loading image I need to transfer it into second thread.

After some googling I realized that I need to implement Callable interface to each thread and than use it with ExecutorService. The problem is that I don't understant how to pass data, for example, from first thread to second.

Can anyone show a simple example of it? thanks

Comment: Seems like you cannot use or show the image before finishing the download. But if you finish downloading the image, then you can pass it to step 2 and 3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [BlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) and a [Producer-Consumer pattern](http://dhruba.name/2011/05/21/the-producer-consumer-pattern-in-java/).

In this approach, the first thread will download your images and put them inside the queue.
The second thread will wait until something appears inside the queue, transform the image, and put it in another queue, that the third thread will wait for.

Read the articles I've linked to for more explanation and a working example of the Producer-Consumer pattern.

Comment: Very short answer. An example would make it awesome.

Comment: @Warpzit: Added some explanaion. The examples are already in the Javadoc (so we can trust they will not disappear), and in the article I linked to. I did not want to copy&paste them ;-).

Comment: thanks for answer, I'll try it.

I have one more question: how can I stop all running threads in any time?

Comment: There is no simple way to do this. One way is to implement a flag, and make a `while` loop inside your thread check this flag and return when it's changed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use java.util.concurrent.Exchanger. This is  synchronization point at which two threads can exchange objects. For more details see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Exchanger.html